# How to access specific attribute value in node object?

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, translate

So I'm coding an html web page and am using the "translate" attribute in different parts of my code like so:

```
<div class="art-nav-outer">
    <div class="art-nav-wrapper">
        <div class="art-nav-inner">
            <ul class="art-hmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                       <span class="l"></span>
                       <span class="r"></span>
                       <span class="t" translate="no">Introduction</span>
                    </a>
                </li>   
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">
                      <span class="l"></span>
                      <span class="r"></span>
                      <span class="t" translate="no">Content</span>
                    </a>
                </li>   
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm looping through the code using `collectTextNodes($('body'));`.

This is the function declaration:

```
function collectTextNodes(element){
  for (var child= element.firstChild; child!==null; child= child.nextSibling) {
     if(child.nodeType === 3 && ...)
        //doaction
     else if(child.nodeType === 1)
       collectTextNodes(child);
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is add a condition to the 'if' which says:

'if the attribute "translate" of the child node is NOT "no"' or 'if the child node does NOT have the attribute "translate"'

then do action

I know there aren't any node Object properties or methods that will return this, but I can't figure what line to write to retrieve it or if it's even possible.

The idea for me is to know when a text needs to be translated or not when searching through the nodes.

Any kind of help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The issue is that when writing:

```
function collectTextNodes(element){
  for (var child= element.firstChild; child!==null; child= child.nextSibling) {
    if(child.nodeType === 3 && ...)
       //doaction
    else if(child.nodeType === 1)
       collectTextNodes(child);
  }
}
```

child.nodeType == 3 returns true for all text nodes and child.hasAttribute("translate") searches if this node has an attribute "translate" but if it's a text node then it won't have any attributes and if it does have the attribute then it won't be a text. In that case the if condition will never be satisfied.

The correct solution is:

```
function collectTextNodes(element, texts){
    for (var child= element.firstChild; child!==null; child= child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3)
        {
            texts.push(child);
        }
        else if (child.nodeType === 1)
        {
          if(!(child.hasAttribute('translate') && $(child).attr('translate') == "no"))
          {
                collectTextNodes(child, texts);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case if the node is an element and this element has an attribute "translate" and the attribute "translate" == "no" then go further down the tree to it's child, else move on to it's next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var child = element.firstChild; child !== null; child = child.nextSibling) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('translate');
    if (child.nodeType === 3 && typeof (attr) === 'undefined') alert('1');
    else if (child.nodeType === 1) collectTextNodes(child);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use class or id names as I want this to work with any node element, class or id which has the attribute "translate". Thus I cannot call for $('.t')  Basically the script should work for any html page in which I insert the "translate" attribute.

Comment: Can you use like this 
var attr=$('.t').attr('translate');
 if(child.nodeType === 3 && typeof(attr)==='undefined')
        //doaction
     else if(child.nodeType === 1)
       collectTextNodes(child);

Comment: you are still using ('.t')